# Why does this simple JSON object throw an error with JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

Anyone can probably figure this out. Why does the following JSON object cause a JSON.parse error? It appears to be a valid JSON object. I'm sure I'm doing something completely idiotic in this, the 14th hour of this long workday.

```
var t = {
    "message": "ok, Heru we go!"
};

JSON.parse(t);

--> syntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Many thank yous!

**UPDATE**

This is the kind of question you ask when you have 2 new puppies and are trying to code on 3 hours of sleep. Please let this serve as a warning for those of you who have come here looking for the same answer- Go to sleep. Give it up. You're worthless today. Try again tomorrow.

Comment: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects a string. The value of `t` is a javascript object, so it doesn't need to be parsed.

If you had:

```
var t = "{\"message\":\"ok, Heru we go!\"}";
```

then `JSON.parse` would be what you were after.

Comment: OH MY LORD I AM AN IDIOT! PLEASE SOMEONE TELL ME TO GO TO SLEEP AND TRY AGAIN IN THE MORNING.

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us. :)

Comment: @Hairgami_Master I have done way worse. Happens. Good night ^^

Answer (score 4):

Don't you want `JSON.stringify(t);`?

`JSON.parse(s);` is used to get the object out of a string.

`JSON.stringify(t);` is used to convert your JSON object to its string equivalent.

Comment: YES YES! I can't believe I'm doing this- can you tell I have two new puppies in my house and am getting absolutely no sleep?

Answer (score 2):

`t` is already a JavaScript object.  `JSON.parse` only works on strings.  You could do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t))`, but that would be kind of pointless.

Comment: Thank you! I'm beyond sleep deprived and can't believe I even posted this question. I will not try and delete it as a warning to those of us who try and program on little to no sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON here should be a string. You are passing an object as parameter.
Try this

```
JSON.parse('{ "message": "ok, Heru we go!" }');
```